# Iterate backwards over a selectedListViewItemCollection

Tags: c#, iteration

I have tried this code (which works for anything that implements IEnumerable, but apparently not a selectedListViewItemCollection)

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in ((IEnumerable<ListViewItem>)categoryListView.SelectedItems).AsEnumerable().Reverse())
{
    // do something
}
```

I get an InvalidCastException when this is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `SelectedItems` does not implement generic `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>`.

Use `Cast<T>` method instead:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in categoryListView.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().AsEnumerable().Reverse())
```